# Alias|Wavefront .mtl File "decal" Command

Tags: texture, material

There are material color and texture colors (e.g. `Kd 0.8 0.8 0.8` vs. `map_Kd diff.png`).  [The documentation](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/) says of this:

> During rendering, the map_Kd value is multiplied by the Kd value.

However, then there is a `decal` command, which specifies a different relation:

> During rendering, the Ka, Kd, and Ks values and the map_Ka, map_Kd, and map_Ks values are blended according to the following formula:
>
> result_color=tex_color(tv)*decal(tv)+mtl_color*(1.0-decal(tv))
>
> where tv is the texture vertex.
>
> "result_color" is the blended Ka, Kd, and Ks values.

Essentially, this is saying that the `decal` at a particular `(u,v)` lerps between the texture at that `(u,v)` and the material color.

---

How does one reconcile these two different usages in the documentation?